# Pushed View Controller Not Receiving Data

Tags: swift3, xcode8, pushviewcontroller

### The Problem

I've sent data to other ViewControllers before but could not figure out why this situation was not working. The situation was as follows

1. FirstViewController and SecondViewController existed in different Storyboards
2. My FirstViewController would have some data that it needed to send to SecondViewController just before we programmatically pushed the SecondViewController. This was accomplished by:

   ```
   @IBAction func someButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {    
   let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondStoryBoard", bundle: nil)

       if let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? ResultsViewController {
           secondViewController.var1 = self.var1

           // Sanity check
           print("set secondViewController.var1 to \(self.var1)") // Printed data as expected

           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
       }
   }
   ```

   3. My SecondViewController would test if the data was set correctly in its ViewDidLoad. This was accomplished by:

      ```
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          if let var1 = self.var1 {
              print("SUCCESS: var1 was set!")
          } else {
              print("FAILURE: var1 is nil! Crash imminent") // Printed here, hence my problem
          }
      }
      ```

### Things I tried:

1. Creating getters and setters for var1 in SecondViewController and watching when they were being setted/getted. The variable was being set at the appropriate line by someButtonPressed in FirstViewController but by the time the if let var1 = self.var1 called the getter in FirstViewController, the value was nil.
2. Placing breakpoints on var1 in SecondViewController. I saw the variable be initialized to nil, as it is an optional, set and later set back to nil (again without calling the setter a second time)

Answer (score 0):

### Finding The Problem

The problem lies in the following screenshot of SecondViewController's View.

*(Note: Let ResultsViewController = SecondViewController)*

[image: Let ResultsViewController = SecondViewController]

As you can see from the picture, this isn't the standard simple View you find in guides on how to pass data from one ViewController to another. My problem lied in the fact that we had one View embedding another. I did not realize, even though its listed in Xcode's interface builder, that embeds are a type of segues.

When was passing data to SecondViewController, I overlooked the outer View that was embedding the inner View. Both Views had their custom class set to SecondViewController, but that just masked the problem with the breakpoint situation described above.

What was happening was, I'd instantiate the outer View, set the data to its SecondViewController successfully and then it'd segue to its inner view and said inner view's SecondViewController would have the default nil values.

---

### The Solution

To solve this problem I wrote a

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "secondViewController") {
        if let secondViewController = segue.destination  as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewController.var1 = self.var1
        }
    }
}
```

in the SecondViewController so that when the Outer View segue'd to the inner, it'd pass its data along.

I also probably should have had both Views, inner and outer, have separate ViewControllers to avoid confusion.